# Mysql order result by the sum of some similar column values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

There are two tables and i am trying to get the values  from one table and order by the sum of values from the other table.

So just to clear i am trying to get the list of all the posts order by sum of meta_key where meta key is like *reaction*%

Here is what i have tried

```
ORDER BY ( SELECT SUM(CAST(meta_value AS UNSIGNED)) as count FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` LIKE '_reaction_button%' GROUP BY post_id )
```

but unfortunately that doesn't work. So is there any solution to this. I think this can be done using view or stored procedures but figure out how.

Actually i am using wordpress and using query_posts to get the posts but it seems like i can't do this with query_posts or WP_Query that's why i am writing custom query. If this can be done with query_posts or WP_Query then it would really be great.

[image: Here is my main table]

[image: Another table where post_id is the foreign key to the first table]

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

First create a temporay table to hold sum values . Then do a join with wp_post table and use order by on sum column of temporary table

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempTable (postID int,countSum int)

INSERT INTO tempTable
SELECT post_id,SUM(CAST(meta_value AS UNSIGNED))
FROM `wp_postmeta` 
GROUP BY post_id


SELECT wp_post.* FROM `wp_post`
INNER JOIN tempTable
  ON wp_post.ID=tempTable.postID 
ORDER BY countSUM

DROP TABLE tempTable
```

Comment: I think you got it wrong i want to select from wp_post and order by the sum from the wp_postmeta table So it would be something like Select * from wp_posts but order by from wp_postmmeta.

Answer (score 0):

```
select p.*
from 'wp_post' p
join (
    select post_id, sum(cast(meta_value as unsigned)) as sum_val
    from 'wp_postmeta'
    where 'meta_key' like '_reaction_button%'
    group by post_id
) pm on p.post_id = pm.post_id
order by pm.sum_val
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not really need direct mysql for that , you could [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

```
$query = new WP_Query( array ( 
                             'post_type' => 'post', 
                             'meta_key' => 'vote_field', 
                             'orderby' => 'meta_value', 
                             'order' => 'ASC' ) );
```

you can also use `meta_compare` or

```
'meta_key' => 'metadata1',
'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'
```

Then you can also use `'compare' => 'LIKE'` or `'compare' => 'NOT LIKE'`

or you can look at this example here : [Wordpress Sum meta_values from posts and order them per category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407359/wordpress-sum-meta-values-from-posts-and-order-them-per-category) and change category to what you need ..

Comment: what do you mean by sum of all ?  you would want to order them no ?